# Express, React, Node.js POST route 404 not found

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am having a problem when attempting to upload a file via a post request, receiving error:

> POST http://localhost:8080/api/files 404 (Not found).

The url of the page I am trying to upload the file from is `http://localhost:8080/playlist/f9aeb4fd-f6c3-46a2-b269-20ae8508e612`, but when I try change my `POST` request to `http://localhost:8080/playlist/f9aeb4fd-f6c3-46a2-b269-20ae8508e612/api/files` by changing `app.use('/api', require('./file'))` to `app.use('/playlist/f9aeb4fd-f6c3-46a2-b269-20ae8508e612/api'`, `require('./file'))` I still receive the same error.

**server.js**

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';
import path from 'path';

import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

import './initialize-db';
import { authenticationRoute } from './authenticate';

let port = process.env.PORT || 7777;
let app = express();


app.use(
    cors(),
    bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}),
    bodyParser.json()
);
let server = app.listen(port,console.info("Server running, listening on port ", port));

authenticationRoute(app);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV == `production`) {
    app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname,'../../dist')));
    app.get('/*',(req,res)=>{
        res.sendFile(path.resolve('index.html'));
    });
}

mongoose.connect(myMongoUrl);

app.use(function(req, res, next) { //allow cross origin requests
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE, GET");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    next();
});

app.use('/api', require('./file'));

module.exports = server;
```

**file.js**

```
const router = require('express').Router();
import multer from 'multer';
import {mongo, connection} from 'mongoose';
import Grid from 'gridfs-stream';
Grid.mongo = mongo;
let gfs = Grid(myMongoUrl);

// set up connection to db for file storage
const storage = require('multer-gridfs-storage')({
   db: connection.db,
   file: (req, file) => {
      return {
         filename: file.originalname
      }
   }
});
// sets file input to single file
const singleUpload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('file');


router.get('/files/:filename', (req, res) => {
   gfs.files.find({ filename: req.params.filename }).toArray((err, files) => {
      if(!files || files.length === 0){
         return res.status(404).json({
            message: "Could not find file"
         });
      }

      let readstream = gfs.createReadStream({
         filename: files[0].filename
      })
      res.set('Content-Type', files[0].contentType);
      return readstream.pipe(res);
   });
});

router.get('/files', (req, res) => {
   gfs.files.find().toArray((err, files) => {
      if(!files || files.length === 0){
         return res.status(404).json({
            message: "Could not find files"
         });
      }
      return res.json(files);
   });
});

router.post('/files', singleUpload, (req, res) => {
   if (req.file) {
      return res.json({
         success: true,
         file: req.file
      });
   }
    res.send({ success: false });
});

router.delete('/files/:id', (req, res) => {
   gfs.remove({ _id: req.params.id }, (err) => {
      if (err) return res.status(500).json({ success: false })
      return res.json({ success: true });
   })
})

module.exports = router;
```

**TaskDetail.jsx**

```
import React, { Component }  from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class TaskDetail extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        files: [],
        file: ''
      }

      this.loadFiles = this.loadFiles.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.loadFiles();
    }

    loadFiles() {
      fetch('/api/files')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(files => {
          if (files.message) {
            console.log('No Files');
            this.setState({ files: [] })
          } else {
            this.setState({ files })
          }
        });
    }

    fileChanged(event) {
      const f = event.target.files[0];
      this.setState({
        file: f
      });
    }

    deleteFile(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      const id = event.target.id;

      fetch('/api/files/'+id, {
        method: 'DELETE'
      }).then(res => res.json())
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response);
          if (response.success) this.loadFiles()
          else alert('Delete Failed');
        })
    }

    uploadFile(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let data = new FormData();
        data.append('file', this.state.file);

        fetch('/api/files', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: data
        }).then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => {
            if (data.success) {
              this.loadFiles();
            } else {
              alert('Upload failed');
            }
          });
      }

    render() {
      const { files } = this.state;
      return(
        <div className="card p-3 col-6">
          <input type="file" onChange={this.fileChanged.bind(this)}/>
          <button onClick={this.uploadFile.bind(this)}>Upload</button>
          <table className="App-table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>File</th>
                  <th>Uploaded</th>
                  <th>Size</th>
                  <th></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {files.map((file, index) => {
                var d = new Date(file.uploadDate);
                return (
                  <tr key={index}>
                    <td><a href={`http://localhost:8080/api/files/${file.filename}`}>{file.filename}</a></td>
                    <td>{`${d.toLocaleDateString()} ${d.toLocaleTimeString()}`}</td>
                    <td>{(Math.round(file.length/100) / 10)+'KB'}</td>
                    <td><button onClick={this.deleteFile.bind(this)} id={file._id}>Remove</button></td>
                  </tr>
                )
              })}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>

    )
}
}

function mapStateToProps(state,ownProps){
    let id = ownProps.match.params.id;
    let task = state.tasks.find(task=>task.id === id);
    let isOwner = state.session.id === task.owner;
    let groups = state.groups;

    return {
        id,
        task,
        isOwner,
        sessionID: state.session.id,
        groups
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, ownProps){
    let id = ownProps.match.params.id;
    return {
        setTaskCompletion(id,isComplete){
            dispatch(setTaskCompletion(id,isComplete));
        },
        setTaskGroup(e){
            dispatch(setTaskGroup(id,e.target.value));
        },
        setTaskName(e){
            dispatch(setTaskName(id,e.target.value));
        }
        }
    }

export const ConnectedTaskDetail = connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(TaskDetail);
```

Comment: are you POSTing to :8080 but your server is listening on :7777 ?

Comment: This was the issue! Thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

As commented by Dan O, issue was with posting to incorrect port.